# Java: Get a list of all present frequencies from an audio input

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, fft, frequency

I am trying to make a program that will return me a list of all frequencies that are present in a WAV. file. I searched a bit about how to achieve this and read that I need to use FFT on the audio input. However I have no idea how to implement FFT and how to handle the data that it delivers. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is non-trivial.  There are lots of fft libraries out there.  But this question is too broad for SO.

Comment: after you find a FFT library I suggest you start with a known signal say a WAV file of say 1000  Hertz  ... write code to read in the WAV file and populate an array with the floating point representation of the audio samples which will start as integers ... normalize those floats from -1.0  to +1.0  ... feed this array into the FFT api call which will return a new array of complex numbers ... iterate acoss this new array and calculate magnitude of each element of array ... verify you have a spike in magnitude at the same frequency as your source input WAV file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Frequencies are a spectrum. In other words infinite. They can not be listed, much like the real numbers can't be listed.    What you probably mean to ask is how to list the *dominant* frequencies?